# Trying to check multiple TXNs & get their data 1 by 1

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I have list of transactions in a file & I have grabbed all of them & I confirmed that they all were grabbed, what I am trying to do is get infos on all transactions 1 by 1

This code is returning me an error

D:\NFT\codes\node_modules@project-serum\anchor\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6853
throw new SolanaJSONRPCError(res.error, 'failed to get transaction');
^

SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get transaction: Invalid param: WrongSize

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import base58 from "bs58";
import * as fs from "fs";
const endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const connect = new anchor.web3.Connection(endpoint);

const txids = fs.readFileSync("Dragon.csv", "utf-8").split("\n");
const URLs = txids.map((txid) => txid.split(",")[2]);
// console.log(URLs)
async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
    const txn = URLs[i].split("tx/")[1];
    console.log(txn);
    const tx = await connect.getParsedTransaction(txn);
    console.log(tx);
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you file looks like but lets say you have  a list of URLs.

This works for me to getting every tx on that list.

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import base58 from "bs58";
import * as fs from "fs";
const endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const connect = new anchor.web3.Connection(endpoint);


const URLs = [
    'https://solscan.io/tx/29UUC2jU95A2ykDJjPDsooYqZ8bdogbm4czJeAUzYrMsdXPW246cvtJTSyqsSPegFnbGEkyYqueWo9SZndCgc4LE',
    'https://solscan.io/tx/5a9drqixAFWse56k8HiXpS66SaMsP59FZjTJVoc5EAK1RPGzZqqeb4VKy6Mqc9HmN5xP5Xucb2evdiXhZPeDGjQs'
]

async function main(urls) {
  for(let url of urls){
    let signature = url.split('/tx/')[1]
    let tx = await connect.getTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');
    console.log(tx)
  }
}

main(URLs);
```